# Create DataFrame from list of dicts with Keys as index

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I would like to create a pandas data from a list of dicts and use the Keys as index 
For example:

```
x = [
     {'AAPL': 0.07969655043031681},
     {'MSFT': 0.04751221896383187},
     {'NFLX': 0.009729232074671192}
    ]
```

I tried pd.DataFrame(x) but the keys are displayed as column and not as index

Could you help please . ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can first create a single dictionary from the list of dictionaries using [`collections.ChainMap`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.ChainMap), and then create a dataframe from it using [`DataFrame.from_dict`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.from_dict.html) and specifying `orient='index'`:

```
from collections import ChainMap
x = [{'AAPL': 0.07969655043031681}, {'MSFT': 0.04751221896383187}, 
     {'NFLX': 0.009729232074671192}]

pd.DataFrame.from_dict(ChainMap(*x), orient='index', columns=['col1'])

        col1
AAPL  0.079697
MSFT  0.047512
NFLX  0.009729
```